# Interchanging limits with difference quotients

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a bounded smooth function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that for any $r\neq 0$, we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|f(x+r)-f(x)|}{|r|} = 0.$$

In particular this means that

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|f(x+r)-f(x)|}{|r|}\right) = 0.$$

Is it possible conclude from this that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{|f(x+r)-f(x)|}{|r|}\right) = 0?$$

Comment: I think this is false. A counter-example is a function whose derivative has a graph that looks like a series of bump functions separated from each other, all of the same height and with decreasing width. Then you can make the widths decrease fast enough that the function still ends up being bounded. In fact, the heights of the bump functions can increase too, so you can get a bounded smooth function with gradient $\rightarrow\infty$ but satisfying the first condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any smooth $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$ while $f'(x)$ fails to have a limit at $\infty$ is a counterexample. Here's one:

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin(e^x)}{1+x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{f(x+r)-f(x)}{r}=g'(0)$

Where $g(r)=f(x+r)$

Thus $$\lim_{r \to 0}|\frac{f(x+r)-f(x)}{r}|=|g'(0)|=|f'(x)|\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to \infty}\lim_{r \to 0}|\frac{f(x+r)-f(x)}{r}|=\lim_{x \to \infty}|f'(x)|$$

Can you find a smooth  bounded function which satisfies the two conditions but $\lim|f'(x)|$ is not zero?

Comment: If $g$ is a function of the variable $r$, why is $g'(0)$ the same as $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+r)-f(x)}{r}$?

Comment: @ougoah....$g'(0)=\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{g(r)-g(0)}{r-0}=\lim{r \to 0}\frac{f(x+r)-f(x)}{r}$

Comment: I see. In any case, the example zhw. gives satisfies the first two conditions in the question but $\lim |f'(x)| \neq 0$. The example I give in the comment below the question also works; that function is monotonic.